# Hermitian and Observables

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, hermitian-matrices

Let $H$ be an finite dim Hilbert space with $|\phi \rangle$ in H, $\langle\phi \mid \phi\rangle=1$, and $\rho \triangleq|\phi\rangle\langle\phi| .$ Let $A$ be an observable which is represented by the Hermitian operator $\hat{A}$ ($\langle A \rangle$ is the avg observation). I've been trying to show the following that:
$$1. \langle A\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho \hat{A}) $$
To prove the above I've been trying to show the eigenvalues of the right hand side are equal to the left, but have been unsuccessful in doing so. Any recommendations would be appreciated
$$2. \operatorname{Tr}(\rho)=1$$
I'm not really sure where to start with this question:
$$3. \rho^{\dagger}=\rho$$
This would show that $\rho$ is hermitian. I've been trying to show that $p = p^\dagger = G^{-1} p G$ where $G$ is the Gram matrix of the space, but have had issues with simplification.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notation but as far as I understand $\rho = x x^*$ where $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ in standard notation. So $tr(\rho) = \sum |x_i|^2 = 1$ and $\rho^* = (x x^*)^* = x x^* = \rho$. But I don't know what an observation is in this context.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The key information that you need for parts 1 and 2 is that for $|\phi\rangle,|\psi\rangle \in H$, we have
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(|\psi \rangle \langle \phi|) = \langle \phi|\psi \rangle.
$$
This can either be shown directly or as a consequence of the general fact that for operators $A,B,$ $\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(BA)$.

For part 3, I have no idea what you mean by the "Gram matrix of the space". This fact can be shown as a consequence of the general fact that for operators $A,B,$ $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$.

Comment: Thanks for your help-- I was able to figure out 2 and 3, but am still a little unsure of how the property you mentioned helps with number 1 (since I'm trying to calculate $Tr(\rho \hat{A})$, I'm unclear on how I'd be able to apply it). One thing I've been trying to do is express $\psi$ and in the eigenbasis of $\hat{A}$, but the math seems messy...

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!

Comment: @invictus135 I'm glad you got it. What I would have said is that 
$$
\operatorname{Tr}\left[\left(\rho |\phi \rangle \right)\langle \phi | \right] = 
\langle \phi | \left(\rho |\phi \rangle \right).
$$